# How use a few partial views in layout? Other ways?

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, partial-views

I have Layout with 2 partial view, what have own 2 models.

```
  @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml",null)

  @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Account/Register.cshtml",null)
```

But another parts of layout do not work.Error

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App2.Models.Search]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'App2.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel'.

Tell me please how to fix it? maybe other way

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App2.Models.Search]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'App2.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel'.

You can try to pass an instance of `LoginModel` into your partial view instead of `null`, like below.

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml", new LoginModel())
```

Comment: it gives error. not found type or namespace LoginModel())

Comment: You can try to add `@using App2.Models.ViewModels` in _ViewImports.cshtml.

Comment: If you can share a reproducible demo, we would help troubleshoot the issue better.